# Fix PHP Notice: 'Undefined index' on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, isset

I'm trying to fix the Undefined index PHP notice on a wordpress site.

At the moment this is what I got:

```
    <?php if($_SESSION['currency-select'] == "a") echo 'selected="selected"';?>
```

I tried to write this way but then the site goes down:

```
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['currency-select'] == "a")) echo 'selected="selected"';?>
```

Also, I have a query which is also without isset and i'm trying to fix it:

```
                    if($_SESSION['currency-select'] == 'b') {

                if($_GET['pricing'] == '1') {

                    $args['meta_query'][] = array(

                        'key' => 'price',

                        'value' => array( '0', '250' ),

                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',

                        'type' => 'numeric'

                    );

                }
```

I tried to write:

```
      if(isset($_GET['pricing'] == '1')) {
      if($_GET['pricing']) {
```

but it doesn't work as well.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: if (isset($_GET['pricing'] == '1'))? What is that? I think you need to use, and meant to use if (isset($_GET['pricing']) { // use it. }

Comment: Quick & Dirty "hideaway" (NOT a fix!): lower your error_reporting level. This hides this type of message, but is only recommended to calm down clients. This is not professionel development.

Comment: Seems like writing the isset function correctly would be quicker and not as dirty

Comment: I'm using `== '1'` just because I have several types of currencies. For example it could also be `== 'money'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try looking if the variable isset and then check the contents of it.

```
if( isset($_GET['pricing']) && $_GET['pricing'] == '1' ){
   //- do some magic
}
```

With your if-clause you check if the clause itself `isset()` instead of the variable.

<s>ps: why do you check the number 1 as a string 1?</s>

Comment: php > $a = 1;
    php > var_dump($a == '1');
    bool(true)

Because php!

Comment: Using == will equate '1' and 1 as the same. I think the OP was thinking IF ISSET RETURN VALUE = 1 THEN USE IT

Answer (score 5):

Simply convert your faulty isset() check.

```
if (isset($_GET['pricing'])) {
    $pricing = $_GET['pricing'];
}
```

The short hand version would look like this, if you want to assign a default value.

```
$pricing = (isset($_GET['pricing'])) ? $_GET['pricing'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if currency_select is set.

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['currency_select'])) echo "selected='selected'";?>
```

Comment: but how can I check if it is set just to a specific value? `['currency_select'] == 'something'` ?

Comment: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['currency_select']) && $_SESSION['currency_select'] == 'something') echo "selected='selected'";?>

Comment: thanks that was the right way to do it. I saw that @strub was first to do this kind of if statement so I marked his answer. Thanks!